# write desktop application in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

I wrote a web application(automation system), i need to alarm user when new mail recived.

I can not write this with c# (`win-form`) because i have to install `.net frame work`,so i want to know is any way to write a simple application using `java-script` or other simple frame work that may you know, to check for new mail and alarm to user in windows ("like a desk app").this is possible?

**Updated**

So i decide to use `vbscript` i find a simple example.

> Example: The following example demonstrates how to write a simple
>   vbscript to open notepad.exe:
>
> 1. Open Notepad and paste the following code into a new document:
>
>    Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
>      Dim exeName
>      Dim statusCode
>      exeName = "%windir%\notepad"
>      statusCode = WshShell.Run (exeName, 1, true)
>      MsgBox("End of Program")
> 2. Save the file as Example.vbs (manually change the extension to .vbs)
> 3. Double-click Example.vbs to run the program which launches Notepad.exe

how can i get query from remote sql server.is this possible?

Comment: The .Net Framework is included with Windows.

Comment: IIRC, XP comes with .Net 1.0 or 1.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows has a JavaScript compiler **jsc.exe** which is normally pre-installed that can be used to create standalone code.

[How to: Compile JScript Code from the Command Line](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7435xtz6%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

It is JScript rather than JavaScript.

jsc.exe is rarely used for standalone scripts so I think you'll struggle to find examples. You would be better off writing VBScript or PowerShell scripts for Windows IMO.

Comment: is it possible to get query from sql db with vbscript.see my edit

Comment: I don't know much about connecting to a remote database with a script. I assume that you need to create a DSN and you may have to configure FireWall settings. [link](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1431304).

Comment: This is JScript.Net.  You can also use C#.